# What does (unreachable) directory mean

Tags: linux, filesystems

In linux (debian), suddenly I see a directory named as 'unreachable'.

What does it mean?

```
drwxr-xr-x    3 user0    user0          224 Mar  9 22:50 (unreachable)
```

Edit: It is an embedded device that has several other directories in the same path. One day I have found this unreachable directory. I suspected that there is some corruption.

Comment: It could mean there is a directory called (unreachable). But I'm guessing that *isn't* the actual name?

Comment: Is the file on a remote mount? Is there something inside?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Please see edited part.

Comment: Do you happen to know the exact filesystem type (jffs, ...) this folder is on?

Comment: @DanielB ubifs.

Comment: Okay, so the `(unreachable)` comes from a Linux fs function `prepend_unreachable`. However, I don’t entirely understand the conditions that would lead to this method being called. It’s in the `getcwd` syscall.